# Am I on the right track with my homework?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need a little help with my homework.

This is the assingment:
If:
$$
U(x):= \frac{(x+2)^2}{x+1}
$$
**For what real numbers $x$ is defined:**
I tried to do that by solving the equation for $x$.
I did that in following manner:
$$
\frac{(x+2)^2}{x+1} = x+3+\frac{1}{x+1}
$$
I got this solution by dividing $(x+2)^2$ with $x+1$.
At the end I got that $x$ is $-1$ and $-3$.

Am I on a good track?? Thanks.

Comment: It's defined for every $x\ne -1$

Comment: Thanks. When I wrote question I figured that out. I fell a little bit stupid right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your division is correct, but unnecessary.

What we know, however, is that $U(x)$ is defined for all $x\in \mathbb R, \;\;x \neq -1$. When $x = -1$, the denominator of $U(x)$ is zero, and division by zero is undefined.

Comment: This also needs a TU! +1

Comment: A rain of $+$ for you. :-)